# React-native: Show Text in Render (return) with conditional

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to show some message to the user if some values' variable.

I have a code like this:

```
connection(device, side) {
//....
if(side == "right"){
this.setState({deviceRight: true})
}
}

renderConnection(connectionProgress){
  switch(connectionProgress) {
  case 1: 
    if(this.state.deviceRight == true){
     return(<View><Text>Device Right Connected</Text></View>)
}
  default: 
   return null;
}

render() {

 const {connectionProgress} = this.state
 return (
     <Text>Waiting for connection..</Text>
     {this.renderConnection(connectionProgress)}
)
}
}
```

So i would to show a text when a variable (for example `deviceRight` is set to "true").

How can I do?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Basically What I wrote in ghte switch case is not displayed

Comment: Bind the ```renderConnection``` with this, for example ```renderConnection = (connectionProgress) =>```.

Comment: I have tried but doens't appear nothing..

Answer (score 1):

I have solved in this way:

```
connection(device, side) {
//....
if(side == "right"){
this.setState({deviceRight: true})
}
}

renderConnection(){
  if(this.state.deviceRight == true)
     {
      return <Text>Device Connected </Text>
     }
 else {
   return <Text> Device not Connected</Text>}
}

render() {
 return (
     <Text>Waiting for connection..</Text>
     {this.renderConnection()}
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ternary operator in this case like below -

```
render() {
 return (
   <View>
     <Text>Waiting for connection..</Text>
     {this.state.deviceRight ? (
       <Text>Device Connected </Text>
     ) : (
     <Text> Device not Connected</Text>
     )}
   </View>
  )
}
```